# How to Get keypress event in extjs charts

Tags: extjs, charts, selection, keypress

This is related to ExtJs 4.2 Charts.

I am stuck where i need to make selection of multiple columns in a column chart only when a user press ctrl key + column selection with mouse click. So, i couldn't find how to capture control key press event in itemclick event of chart.

Please send in your suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot at a direction you might take and not a definitive answer.

You might look at adding a couple listeners to the Panel or Viewport you are working with, add a keydown event and the keyup event, not sure if that will work, you might go so far as to add it to the DOM models window too.  You see the problem I am seeing here is that you have to have focus first on something, and you will probably at least have the focus of the window, where if you, put this listener on the actual chart you have to focus there by clicking on the chart first and then selecting the key and then clicking again, kind of a lot of actions I would think and not intuitive.

Then set a global variable to true on the key press down and back to false on the key press up.

Then in the itemmousedown event that you also create on the charts Series so you can read the variable and use it as you intend.

here is what the listener should look like

```
series: [{
    type: 'column',
    ...
    listeners: {
        itemmousedown: function(item, eOpts) {
            .... // get your global variable here.
            console.log(item);
            console.log(eOpts);
        }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually i tried that and was able to add event to the containing panel but then i found out a basic issue with HTML that the keypress events are not triggered from a div element which are rendered while using panel. Anyways i found a solution which i will be explaining below.

Comment: If oyu come up with a solution would love ot see it, throw it into a sencha fiddle maybe.

Comment: Brian H, My solution is based on my original approach explained in post above and it is working fine so far...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution it is working fine but its a kind of workaround.

Here is the code snippet...

```js
var bIsControlkeyPressed=false;

function setCtrlKey(event){
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
        bIsControlkeyPressed=true;
    }else{
        bIsControlkeyPressed=false;
    }
  alert(bIsControlkeyPressed)
}
```

```html
<body onmousedown = "setCtrlKey(event)">hello</body>
```

When you click anywhere on page (body part i.e. 'hello' in  this case), this code will set the global flag to true if ctrl key is also pressed else false is set. I know there are other ways this can be done but this approach works with IE8 also :)